# Form submission React

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        
        const data = { atmName: '', atmType: '', terminalId: '', branchName: '', branchCode: '', branchAddress: '', vendor: '', createdBy: '' }
        axios.post(`${apiAddress}/atmterminal/single`, data).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {console.log(error)}) 
        setTerminal(initialFormState);
      }
```

Please what is wrong with this code as I get error 400

Comment: 400 is backend error for `bad request` so did you check the call from postman if it's working?

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging your request to the API first and see if something is wrong with the request you are sending.

As Adel said in the comments, 400 is an invalid request so you probably have something wrong in your syntax.

Edit:

1. Have you defined apiAddress?
2. Should it be **atmTerminal** following the syntax of the other parameters?